# Is there any way to find newly added devices using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to find newly added device like usb, mouse, cd-rom etc? using asp.net with c#
when we use this method it gives information about all devices

```
 DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

 foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}, Type {1}", d.Name, d.DriveType);
 }
```

We can also find the removable device like usb using DriveType method but when attach external cd-rom with my system it shows same as other CD-rom which is already attach with my system.

I am using system.Io library.

Is there any way to differentiate previous and newly added cd-Rom. one thing more we don't have any idea how much new devices user can attach to the system, i mean to say he/she can attach as many devices as they want. we can't restrict them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can get the newly added devices without build your own watcher:

ex: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx

A simpler solution, you can save the previously readed devices on a list/DB and compare the new getted list with the saved.

BTW: In this way you will the get the attached drives on **server**, is it right? If you wanna get the client devices list you have to change the approach at all.